# seleccionar el elemento hermano siguiente con CSS

Tags: html, css, pseudoelementos

Estoy intentando replicar un input similar a los de materialize.
Entonces el problema es el siguiente...

Tengo un input y un label, ambos con la misma clase, lo que quiero es (con CSS) saber que cuando el input NO ESTE VACIO entonces seleccionar el siguiente elemento hermano con la misma clase y poder asignarle atributos.
Pero no logro hacerlo...

```css
body{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
form{
width: 350px;
padding: 10px;
}
.content-input{
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
.content-input label{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 7px;
    left: 2px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.content-input input{
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0px 5px 2px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(138, 38, 38, 0.371);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: .4s;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
.content-input input:focus-visible{
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0  #08B;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}
.content-input input:focus-visible{
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0  #08B;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}

/*Se supone que con esta linea lograria eso, pero simplemente no funciona*/
.cardinal-input[value]:not(:empty) + .cardinal-input{
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form Materialize</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <div class="content-input">
            <input type="text" class="cardinal-input" value="34"> 
            <label for="textInput" class="cardinal-input">Prueba</label>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- <script src="main.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el `placeholder-shown`, básicamente para que cuando no se muestre el placeholder es porque el input esta lleno. De esta forma validas que tenga datos y modificas conforme necesites. Cabe mencionar que necesitar poner el atributo placeholder en tu input para que funcione.

```css
body{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
form{
width: 350px;
padding: 10px;
}
.content-input{
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
.content-input label{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 7px;
    left: 2px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.content-input input{
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0px 5px 2px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(138, 38, 38, 0.371);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: .4s;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
.content-input input:focus-visible{
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0  #08B;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}
.content-input input:focus-visible{
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0  #08B;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}


/*Se supone que con esta linea lograria eso, pero simplemente no funciona*/
.cardinal-input:not(:placeholder-shown) + .cardinal-input{
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form Materialize</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <div class="content-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="" class="cardinal-input" value=""> 
            <label for="textInput" class="cardinal-input">Prueba</label>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- <script src="main.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar el atributo required al input, luego en tu selector hacer lo siguiente

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
form{
width: 350px;
padding: 10px;
}
.content-input{
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
.content-input label{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 7px;
    left: 2px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.content-input input{
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0px 5px 2px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(138, 38, 38, 0.371);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: .4s;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
.content-input input:focus-visible{
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0  #08B;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}
.content-input input:focus-visible{
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0  #08B;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}
.cardinal-input:not(:invalid) + .cardinal-input {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

Y tu HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form Materialize</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <div class="content-input">
            <input type="text" class="cardinal-input" value="34" required> 
            <label for="textInput" class="cardinal-input">Prueba</label>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- <script src="main.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```